# Tooltip for bootstrap-sass is not work

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, tooltip, bootstrap-sass

Used bootstrap-sass in my vue project, but the tooltip is not work.
Below is my code:

```
<span class="fa fa-fast-backward page-item-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="First Page"></span>
```

According to bootstrap document, we must initialize tooltip before use it. So I just add this code in my main.js, and it works well.

```
// Initialize all tooltips of bootstrap.
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to bootstrap document, we must initialize tooltip before use it. So I just add this code in my main.js, and it works well.

```
// Initialize all tooltips of bootstrap.
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
```